# Pandas printing options

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to print different number format information (not the 'e' form. Example: Now is printed as -1.0e-02, I would like to see 1.000, with 3 digits after dot) in my console.

- Pandas 0.18.1
- Python 2.7

**Python code**

```
from pandas import set_option
set_option('display.width', 100)
set_option('precision', 3)
correlations = transformed_data['train'].corr(method='pearson')
print(correlations)
```

**Output**

```
    col0       col2   col4      col10  col11  col12      label      col14
col0   1.000e+00 -8.636e-05 -0.016  7.884e-02  0.049 -0.007  2.350e-01 -1.497e-02
col2  -8.636e-05  1.000e+00 -0.001 -1.936e-03 -0.003  0.019 -1.670e-03  1.068e-02
col4  -1.561e-02 -1.425e-03  1.000 -7.065e-03 -0.006  0.006  4.412e-03 -6.901e-03
col10  7.884e-02 -1.936e-03 -0.007  1.000e+00 -0.032  0.001  2.271e-01 -2.332e-04
col11  4.870e-02 -2.979e-03 -0.006 -3.157e-02  1.000 -0.003  1.416e-01 -5.507e-03
col12 -6.520e-03  1.852e-02  0.006  1.114e-03 -0.003  1.000  3.778e-03 -9.215e-03
label  2.350e-01 -1.670e-03  0.004  2.271e-01  0.142  0.004  1.000e+00  7.549e-04
col14 -1.497e-02  1.068e-02 -0.007 -2.332e-04 -0.006 -0.009  7.549e-04  1.000e+00
```

**Data types**

```
print(transformed_data['train'].dtypes)

    col0     float64
    col1      object
    col2     float64
    col3      object
    col4     float64
    col5      object
    col6      object
    col7      object
    col8      object
    col9      object
    col10    float64
    col11    float64
    col12    float64
    col13     object
    label      int64
    col14    float64
```

Comment: you have values which are much smaller than the precision that you have mentioned. For example `-8.636e-05` is `-0.00008636`. Since you have `set_option('precision', 3)`, it will remain in Scientific notation format. And to maintain constant format throughout each column of the dataframe, the entire column remains in Scientific notation. You could use a more precise decimal point to ensure Non-scientific notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned `set_option('precision', 3)`, the DataFrame displays any `value` in `1.000` (example) format just like you need, 
EXCEPT when `value < 1e-3` (or `0.001`).

In such a situation, the value cannot be truncated to `0.000`. Thus, Scientific notation is preserved.
But, A Pandas DataFrame maintains one constant display format for each column. So, the Scientific notation is preserved in the entire column that contains `value < 1e-3`

To make sure all values are displayed in non-scientific format, you can use:

```
set_option('precision', 6)
```

OR you can truncate or round all the values before storing it in the DataFrame