# How to change float (scientific values) in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
loc1      [0.0124,0.12243,0.2345....]  [2.3e-7,0.12334,0.2344....]
loc2      [0.3356,0.12301,0.1345....]  [0.0333,0.12334,0.2314....]
loc3      [0.0335,0.12334,0.2344....]  [0.0335,1.2e-5,0.2384....]
....
```

There are many instances in the 2nd column where there is an e notation. I am trying to change this to a numeric in pandas.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas printing options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44645005/pandas-printing-options)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the pandas formatting:

```
pd.set_option('precision', 4)
```

or define your own formatter:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.4f' % x)
```

or you can simply just round your values

```
df.round({'column_name': 4})
```